# How to get path of stroke using opencv?

Tags: c++, python, image-processing, opencv, 2d

I want to get path stroke from image using opencv. I know how to get contours but I need path of stroke (path that runs through the center of the stroke). Is it possible to get this in opencv ?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? What kind of an image?

When you say stroke, you're talking about an image whose length is significantly longer than its width. And you want to trace the mid point of the path in this image from one end to the other?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV does not have a skeletonization algorithm that allows one to get a stroke path.  You would need to implement an existing algorithm, good place to start is here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton